# formula for mysql performance with number of queries

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a formula that relates to the number of queries and the impact on response time from a MySQL database?

or any other simple understanding that we can know how much our website can hold up depends on the number of hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
set profiling=1;
```

Run your query and do:

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

Answer (score -1):

No. Execution time will depend sevral factors such as database design, indexes and the length of data stored and what query your running.

If you need specific help optimising one query we can help you. I suggest you check out the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)